# How to Write SQL funtion

Tags: sql

How Create a function/s to extract the middle names from a string of text. Also ensure that any
record with a pattern like customer no. “Hill James I.” is placed in the appropriate columns
e.g. The first name goes in to the last_name column, the first name “James” goes into the
first_name column and the initial “I.” goes into the middle_name column.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Post your attempt and your issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 1) as last_name,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as first_name,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) as middle_name from <>;